# Windows Powershell how to disable loading of an unwanted module

Tags: command-line, powershell, git

Just like in question, here are lines of code that I used that may have caused the problem. I was installing Git for powershell

```
. (Resolve-Path "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\GitHub\shell.ps1")
. $env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1
```

and after these lines I quote

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm
 cd ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\posh-git
.\install.ps1
```

"This will add the proper line to your profile.ps1 file, and posh-git will be active the next time you open your prompt"
And here is the problem, everytime I launch powershell I get import-module error (I deleted the files of git and installed it in a different way)

Comment: Could you please provide the full error details you get when you launch powershell?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

PS Modules when installed are loaded from several locations.
You can get the list of such locations using variable in PS session: `$env:psmodulePath`.

Thus browsing through all of such locations find a folder with newly installed module and remove it.